# nonBindable single curly bracket in html of an element :angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, expression, curly-braces

I need to show single curly bracket in my application. Something like this:
`...demo text .... {name} ...some more text ...`
While compiling angular reaches EOF. Is there a way i can escape this single curly bracket?

Other than that i need to evaluated nested expressions in Angular 2. Something like 
`{{var1 {{var2 {{var3}} var4}} var5}}`
Unable to find any workaround for that. Any other way i can implement that?

Comment: show your component code

Answer (score 3):

To print curly braces use [ng-non-bindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) , still available in angular2

```
<div ngNonBindable>
...demo text .... {name} ...some more text ...
</div>
```

for `{{var1 {{var2 {{var3}} var4}} var5}}` nested, I think this be better if you evaluate in controller.js

**Edit**

I think aforementioned solution is not appropriate as **ngNonBindable** directive is dicey.

```
template: `<div> {{ '{' }} I'm inside curly bracket } </div>`
```

simply escape the first curly brace, this should work.

Comment: it's for angular.js, he is asking about angular

Comment: updated, I think angular2 has missed the documentation for this directive.

Comment: right, but it's [not a directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_preparser.ts#L19) though :) but should work. Replace the link to Angular.js with the link to sources - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_preparser.ts#L19

Comment: wrong answer, `<div ngNonBindable>...demo text .... {name} ...some more text ...</div>` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you need to do

```
...demo text .... {{ '{' }}name{{ '}' }} ...some more text ...
```

because it is ngnonbindable. it will work fine on plane html but not in angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<div>{{'{'}} "object": [] {{'}'}}</div> // output: { "object": [] }
```

**OR**

Create variables on the component side with the strings you need to use, then in the template use them with binding.

component.ts

```
imports ...
export class ... {
    leftCB = '{';
    rightCB = '}';
}
```

component.html

```
<div>{{leftCB}} "object": [] {{rightCB}}</div> // output: { "object": [] }
```

CYA!

Answer (score 0):

My advice: if you need to do string operations or deep object lookups, do that in the component code, not in the template.

re nested evaluation: AFAIK that's not possible